# New light fixture won't turn off

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, canada

I tried installing a light fixture in a previously unused light box (so cannot use how previous light was wired as a baseline).

My light fixture has a black live wire, a white neutral wire and a green ground wire.

The box in the ceiling has 2 black wires twisted together, 2 white wire twisted together, a red wire and a bare copper wire.

I wired the black box wires to the fixture black wire, the whites to the white, the copper to the green and left the red wire alone.

When I turned the breaker back on, the light was on and flipping the switch did not turn it off.

I replaced the switch, but that did not do anything.

My best guess is I wired it wrong but I have no idea what the right configuration would be.

Edit:
Connecting the black light wire to the red ceiling wire fixed the issue. Thank you!

[image: Diagram of the wires as best as I can see]

Comment: I am betting that if you turn off the breaker and take out the switch, you will find a black wire and a red wire.  If so connect black light wire to red wire, and white to white.  Report what you find before doing.

Comment: The Switch _was_ connected to a black wire and a red wire. Huh, I'll try that.

Comment: Just wondering how white wire is done at the switch?  In your case it should probably have a wire nut on the end at the switch.

Comment: Well, that was from when I changed the switch to see if that was the problem, at the time I didn't poke around too much and just disconnected the 2 wires (1 black, 1 red) connected to the old switch and connected them to the new one. I didn't take out the white wires to see what they were attached to.

Comment: You really only need two wires(plus ground) going to switch.  One wire(white) is not needed and should be disconnected at both ends and have a wire nut placed on both ends.  Most people would just a two wire cable(white and black) and put black tape/paint on white wire to show it was hot(switch hot).

Comment: @crip659 Ever since NEC 2011 you are required to bring neutral on a switch loop.  That is specifically to accommodate smart switches. I don't see a point in disconnecting it up at the lamp, since this will only make more work for the person installing a smart switch.

Comment: @Harper - Reinstate Monica  Thank you, I learn something everyday from the good people on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I suspect you have (ignoring the grounds) is:

- One cable coming in with hot (black) and neutral (white)
- One cable coming in white hot (black), neutral (white) and **switched hot** (red).

The hots all connect together. *Do not touch them.*

The neutrals all connect together. *Add your light's white = neutral to this bundle.*

The switched hot connects to your light's black wire so that it is *switched*.

Colors, except green/ground and *mostly* white/neutral have no inherent meaning. But in standard cables, you will normally have black = hot and red = switched hot. (Except when you don't.)

Note that in the good 'ol days, a switch like this would have *two* wires in the box, not three. So you would have black and white but no neutral. New code requires neutral in the box, therefore /3 cable, therefore white = neutral, *even if neutral isn't actually being used.* When neutral isn't used, the white wire is capped in the switch box. But that is good because if you decide to add a smart switch, timer, etc. then you have neutral ready and waiting.

Comment: Re white wires follow the advice in this answer to connect the whites in the ceiling box and leave it capped in the switch box.  There's a comment saying you should cap it at both ends.   By following this answer, if you later want to install a fancier switch it'll be a five minute job.  (EG, Smart switch, timer, night light, combo outlet, etc).